# Setting region grow threshold by layer value difference using eCognition?

Tags: ecognition

I'm trying to use the "grow region"-algorithm in eCognition Developer 9 on an yet almost unclassified 1x1 (=pixel resolution) chessboard segmentation. I classified nothing but my "seed points" by a thematic layer yet.

I have a single layer that I want to use for growing ("infinite cycles", as much as possible) as long as the candidate neighbors value in this layer is within a specific distance.

f.e.: let's say i don't want to add a neighbor if the value difference exceeds +-2.

How could i do this within a ruleset?